# Draw circle in middle of a table cell

Tags: html, css

How can I draw a perfect circle inside a table cell I know using `border-radius:50%;` can draw the circle but when the cell not have the same width and height the circle is not perfect. I try to do something like the figure.

[image]

**How can I do this just with `CSS`?**

Comment: Could you provide some code showing what you tried so far?

Comment: this is my CSS `text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;border-radius:50%;background:blue;border:5px double gray;background-origin:content-box!important;`

Comment: Put your code in your question, please.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. A circle is a circle. It doesn't care where it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if this helps but simply give your circle a high and width so it will always be the same size.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{
  padding:5px;
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
.circle{
  background-color:blue;
  display:block;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:5px solid #000;
  margin:auto;
  color:#fff;
  line-height:50px;
  text-align:center
  
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>some Text</td>
    <td>
      <span class="circle">
        text
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text<br>Some text Some text<br> Some text <br>text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>some Text</td>
    <td>
      <span class="circle">
        text
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the percentage to achieve your requirements like:

```
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background: white;
}
```

Responsive circles with text inside: https://codepen.io/nuriarai/pen/uIrFf

Answer (score 1):

Take a look this approach:

```css
.round-button{
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 20% 0%;
  background: white;
  border: solid 5px black;
  text-align: center;
}

table{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

table, td, tr{
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Something</td>        
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td><span class="round-button">TEXT</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Something</td>        
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td><span class="round-button">TEXT</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CSS `background` & `background-size` Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images)

Place a background image of a circle within a tag (ex. `<figure>`), and nest another tag for the text (ex. `<figcaption>`) in the last column of `<td>`s . It scales perfectly see it in full page and the circle is a fixed size (so all circles will be the same dimensions) yet still responsive (so all circles will scale to the viewport dimensions as long as the table is responsive as well).

---

### [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

The `background` is shorthand for a ton of `background-*` properties but we will just use the following:

- `background-image`
- `background-repeat`
- `background-position`

---

### [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

This property determines how the `background-image` behaves:

- `cover` - extends to the borders and if it doesn't fit, it will be cropped*
- `contain` - extends to the borders and stops -- we will use this value.
- Other values are not relevant with this see link provided above for details.
  *<sub>Just mentioning `cover` as a point of interest we will not be using it</sub>

---

### Demo

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font: 400 5vh/7.5vh Consolas;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 65.25%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-height: 7.5vh;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0.5vh 0.5vw;
  width: 25%;
}

tr td:last-of-type {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.circle {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 7.5vw;
  width: 7.5vw;
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/ChN5VkB/circle.png)no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.circle figcaption {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: calc(50% - 3.75vh) auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Text<br>Text<br>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>
      <figure class='circle'>
        <figcaption>Text</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>
      <figure class='circle'>
        <figcaption>Text</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>
      <figure class='circle'>
        <figcaption>Text</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>
      <figure class='circle'>
        <figcaption>Text</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```